# Display only first row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm joining 2 tables and displaying data for InvNumber, InvAmount and JobNumber. I only need to display InvNumber and InvAmount in the first row. The Invoice has multiple Job numbers which should be displayed.

HEre is the DDL

```
DECLARE @Date datetime;
SET @Date = GETDATE();

DECLARE @TEST_DATA TABLE
(
    DT_ID INT       IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   ,InvNumber       VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL
   ,InvAmount       VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL
   ,JobNumber       VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @TEST_DATA (InvNumber, InvAmount,JobNumber) 
VALUES
  ('70001', '12056','J65448')
 ,('70001', '12056','J12566')
 ,('70001', '12056','J35222')
 ,('70001', '12056','J45222')
 ,('70001', '12056','456855')
 ,('70001', '12056','J55254')

;

SELECT 
    J.DT_ID
    ,InvNumber
    ,InvAmount
    ,JobNumber

FROM @TEST_DATA AS J
```

Comment: Show the actual join and what you want the results to to be

Comment: Please provider expected output structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this with ROW_NUMBER and CASE expressions.

```
SELECT  DT_ID,
        CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN InvNumber
                ELSE ''
        END InvNumber,
        CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN InvAmount
                ELSE ''
        END InvAmount,
        JobNumber
FROM    (SELECT DT_ID,
                InvNumber,
                InvAmount,
                JobNumber,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvNumber,InvAmount ORDER BY DT_ID) RN
            FROM   @TEST_DATA
        ) j
```

Comment: @Frisbee they are displayed

Comment: OK I was reading it wrong

Comment: @Frisbee   `I only need to display InvNumber and InvAmount in the **first row**`.. this makes me assume he wants multiple rows for each Job Number, but doesn't want to keep seeing the InvNumber and InvAmount.. i could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

you can't really easily do that with SQL.

You can use the GROUP BY clause, in the select statement, to group the JobNumbers by Invoice though.

Comment: This is doable with SQL, it's possible to get the `row number` and with that there's a couple different methods to only show column data in only the first row.

Answer (score 1):

I am almost in line with JamieD77 answer. But I am not sure if this solution will show all InvNumbers and all InvAmounts if there are several. So, this is what I am suggesting:

```
select  td.DT_ID,
        case when td.DT_ID = j.DT_ID then td.InvNumber
             else ''
        end as InvNumber,
        case when td.DT_ID = j.DT_ID then td.InvAmount
             else ''
        end as InvAmount,
        td.JobNumber
from    @TEST_DATA as td
left join (
           select   InvNumber,
                    InvAmount,
                    min(DT_ID) as DT_ID
           from     @TEST_DATA
           group by InvNumber,
                    InvAmount
          ) j
```